Не подключится на клиенте к express серверу на VPS
Начал деплоить проект (express на VPS, клиент на gh-pages). не могу сделать запрос к серверу с клиента, выдает cors.
Возможно, я неправильно прописал адрес куда делать запрос на клиенте. есть сервер доменных имен (ns5.hosting.reg.ru и ns6.hosting.reg.ru), доменное имя (example.com), ip (12.12.12.12:1212). VPS на порту 1212, сам express сервер на 3000. сначала делал запросы по ip - выдает cors.
app.use(cors()) на express использую
не понимаю в чем ошибка
